# Kotlin. Context problem. Calling internal function in MainActivity from fragment

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I have this function in several fragments of an app.

```
internal fun aToast() {
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "Invalid Input. Try again.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
}
```

I'd like to move the function from the fragments to the MainActivity and make it "internal", so that all fragments can access it from there. If I do that I get a problem with "context". The context should be, I think, the fragment that is making the call. How do you make the function aware of that?

PS. This is not a big deal. It is not much code so it can of course stay in the fragments, but I am new to Kotlin and I want to learn.

Here are some screen shots of the error messages:

[Problem!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJPPR.png)

[Alt+Enter gives this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lOpf.png)

[Both choices give this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uxJS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your aToast() function to take in a Context parameter, which can then be passed from the fragment that calls the function to the MainActivity where it is defined. Here's an example:

```
 internal fun aToast(context: Context) {
     Toast.makeText(
         context,
         "Invalid Input. Try again.",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
     ).show()
  }
```

Then, in your fragment, you can call the aToast() function like this:

```
  aToast(requireContext())
```

This passes the requireContext() function from the fragment as the parameter to the aToast() function, which ensures that the Context used by the Toast is the same as the one from the fragment.

In your MainActivity, you can call the aToast() function in the same way as you would in the fragment, passing in the appropriate Context when needed.

Hope this helps!